# How to use an output stream operator defined in a header

Tags: c++, string, stl, log4cxx

I would like to be able to append the content of any `std::vector<T>` to an output stream. I've found this code:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_H_
#define DEBUG_H_

#include <vector>

template < class T >
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    os << "[";
    for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator ii = v.begin(); ii != v.end(); ++ii)
    {
        os << " " << *ii;
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}


#endif /* DEBUG_H_ */
```

and put in in a header `Debug.h`. How can I use this operator troughout my project?

EDIT: I have verified that this works in a unit test:

```
#include "Debug.h"

TEST_F(AuxGTest, testVectorDebug) {
    std::vector<int> vec(10, 42);
    std::cout << "vec: " << vec << std::endl;
}
```

But using it with log statements of log4cxx does not work:

```
#include <log4cxx>
#include "Debug.h"

namespace Foo {
    class Bar { 
        void foo() {
            std::vector<int> vec(10, 42);
            DEBUG("vec: " << vec);
        }

    }

}
```

This results in the following compiler message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/log4cxx/0.10.0/include/log4cxx/helpers/messagebuffer.h:190:47: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloading operator<<: cannot bind lvalue to ‘std::basic\_ostream<char>&&’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651161/overloading-operator-cannot-bind-lvalue-to-stdbasic-ostreamchar)

Comment: Mostly you just need to include the header in the source file where you want to use the operator, then just do something like `std::cerr << your_vector;`

Comment: @JerryCoffin Try it if the code is in a template, and `T` is one of the basic types, like `int`.  (It might still work with MSVC, but it won't with a compiler which implements C++98 or above.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I interpreted the question as a simple one of how to deploy this code for use in the project, not the rather more complex one of how to actually make the code work under any but the most trivial of conditions (but especially after rereading the question, I'll openly admit that could have been a mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you trying to use it?  As declared, it's in the global
namespace, so it won't be found by ADL unless `T` is a type
defined in the global namespace.  And it won't be found by
normal lookup if you're in a namespace other than global
namespace, and there is an `operator<<` in that namespace (which
would hide it).  It also won't be found if invoked in
a template, if any of the arguments are dependent, since
dependent name lookup only uses ADL.

And of course, you really don't want to do this except in toy
programs.  Different uses of `std::vector` will require
different output formats; it's far better to wrap the
`std::vector` in a class, and define the `operator<<` for the
class, for each different semantic use.  (For toy programs, you
can define the operator in namespace `std`.  Undefined behavior,
but since no one else will ever see the code, or have to
maintain it, and it's not the end of the world if it doesn't
work...)

### EDIT:

Since it seems that you're using this for some sort of tracing
or debugging: this is one case where it does make sense to
support a unified output for `std::vector`, since it is used to
output *internal* state.  On the other hand, it is usual in this
case for the `ostream` to be wrapped, something like:

```
class Logger
{
    std::ostream* myDest;
public:
    Logger( std::ostream* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    Logger& operator<<( T const& value )
    {
        if ( myDest != NULL ) {
            *myDest << value;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This allows runtime configuration of the logging (plus automatic
insertion of things like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, if you use
a macro to get the instance of `Logger`); your macro `DEBUG`
might be something like:

```
#define DEBUG getLogger( TRACELEVEL_DEBUG, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

where `getLogger` is a global function which returns a `Logger`
initialized with the correct `ostream` (or a null pointer, if
logging isn't active for that level).  Once you do this, you can
add special functions, like:

```
template <typename T>
Logger& Logger::operator<<( std::vector<T> const& value )
{
    if ( myDest != NULL ) {
        //  your code here...
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Since one of the arguments the the `<<` operator will be an
instance of `Logger`, ADL will find the operator, regardless.

Comment: I tried to make clear where I use it with a mock example. The actual code would be quite verbose.

Comment: Can you point me to a code example where a `std::vector` is wrapped and an operator `<<` is added?

Comment: @cls Not off hand, but it doesn't seem like a difficult concept.  You define a class which contains an `std::vector` (giving it an interface appropriate for its role in your application), and you write an `operator<<` for that class.

Comment: @cls Re your example: what is in `"log4cxx"`? In particular, does it do anything which might result in the compiler needing ADL to find your `operator<<`?

Comment: @cls Debugging output may be an exception to my statement that you don't want a global output for `vector`.  I've edited my answer to show how I handle the issue.

Comment: What does ADL stand for? log4cxx is an Apache library, which provides the underlying logging macros. `DEBUG` is my macro for for `LOG4CXX_DEBUG(log4cxx::Logger::getRootLogger(), MESSAGE)`. I would like to stick with that, not define another logger.

Comment: @cls ADL is argument dependent lookup.  And I don't know the library, so I cannot say whether it does something which causes outputting vectors to require ADL to find the `<<` (but it looks like it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990898/how-to-overload-the-ostream-operator-to-make-it-work-with-log4cxx-in-c) about user-defined operators with log4cxx. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21036353/3154588) that question by recommending placing the operator in the `log4cxx::helpers` namespace. See .